# Why is Twig sending HTML file from previous response?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using Klein for routing and Twig as template engine. I created 2 routes that work as intended. But When I redirect to /test it sends response from previous /[:name] (Just html, not sql) and /test as well, both stacked on each other (first previous /[:name] then /test).

I tried messing with .htaccess file, but with no success. For INFO I'm using xampp for my localhost and I set up virtual host.

**Php code (index.php)**

```
use Application\Database\connect;
use Application\DisplayData;
use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader;

//Require autoload.php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

//Twig API
$loader = new FilesystemLoader(__DIR__.'\views\HTML');
$twig = new Environment($loader);

//Db connection global variable
$connect = new DisplayData();

//Klein router code
$klein = new \Klein\Klein();

//Home root
$klein->respond('GET', '/', function () use ($twig, $connect, $klein) {
    echo $twig->render('index.html', ['name' => $connect->getData("SELECT * FROM Zapis")]);
});

//Zapisnik seperate page
$klein->respond('GET', '/[:name]', function ($request) use ($twig, $connect, $klein){
    echo $twig->render('zapis.html', ['data' => $connect->GetSeperateData(
        "SELECT * FROM Zapis Where NaslovZapisa = ? limit 1", 
        $request->name
    )]);

});

$klein->respond('GET', '/test', function(){
    return "Hello";
});

$klein->dispatch();
```

**.Htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your `/test` route above `/[:name]`?

Comment: Yes I did and It fixed my problem, going to post answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basicly, problem was that /[:name] and /test send response at the same time beacuse router didn't know the difference between /test that was sent from /[:name] and /test. So I just added /category/[:name] and left /test unchanged. Now It works fine.